# ColdFusion CRUD

Tags: coldfusion, crud

For quite a long time now, I've been trying to write and have been in search of "a really good" CRUD application.  Don't get me wrong - I didn't say "The ultimate" CRUD application.  Just one that could be rated 1st class.

What I'm saying is: Please don't respond to this plea with an answer like "Well, every situation is different..."

Q: Is there a blog post or something in the Adobe documentation that shows CRUD on a one-to-many relationship (Header/Detail), that uses web standards css (instead of tables), that uses best practices (CF9 has changed so many things now: scripted components, ORM), that uses the latest UI techniques (jQuery or some of the built-in AJAX features of CF9), that has a nice front-end (a nice looking header and background along with some pretty buttons)?

I know that's a lot to ask, but such is my quest.
A good example of a one-to-many relationship is the city/state xml files built into the Spry examples.  There are 23,000 cities in the sample xml files, so I think that's better than just using random data.

Comment: What is a "CRUD application"?

Comment: Another thing I'd like is a Test-Driven Development example built into the CRUD application, so that I can push a button and have it run through a battery of tests and respond with a green icon denoting that everything is running ok.

Comment: Al, thanks for the reply.  CRUD stands for Create, Read, Update and Delete.  I want an example that a novice can copy/paste and come up with a really good looking admin menu for the database tables.

Comment: Ah! That last line of the comment helps things make more sense - you basically want a generic (but pretty) admin interface for people not able/allowed to use SQL, but who you want to manage a [subset of a] database with?

Comment: Peter,

With the coming of ORM in CF9, a lot of people are thinking that writing the CRUD portion of an application is all but done for the beginner.  But I think not.  I'm looking for a really good example from beginning to end.  One that meets all the criteria on how a good program that updates the dbs should be written.  If it uses remote access calls, but requires the user to be logged in, how do you handle the security?  etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would strongly suggest you check out [cfwheels](http://cfwheels.org). read the documentation, it's built for doing such crud applications and has an amazing set of features and will save you a lot of time. as for the interface, there are many jquery plugins out there that can handle this. i suggest looking at [ajaxrain](http://www.ajaxrain.com) and find a plugin you like

Comment: rip747, thanks for the advice.  I took a quick read at the Hello World example of cfwheels.  And Ajaxrain looks like quite an impressive library of jQuery code!

Does cfwheels work on a shared hosting environment where I can't do url rewriting?

Comment: cfwheels was designed to work in all types of environments, especially shared hosting. heck, one of the core members of our group owns Alurium hosting.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but I just want to respond to a couple of points in your question (this is more a comment than an answer, but since SO is stupidly limited in this, I'll put it here instead.)

> that uses web standards css (instead of tables),

There is no "css instead of tables" - they are two distinct *and compatible* things!

CSS describes visual aspects of a document, whilst tables markup tabular data.

If you're displaying tabular data, then tables is exactly what you should be using, and you can use CSS to make it look more exciting than the plain styles that tables come in.

Since you're asking for a CRUD app, odds are you are going to be wanting to display tabular data so should be using tables.

(The common mistake people make is not understanding the nature of the web, and using tables to apply grid layouts to documents, when they should be using strucuted semantic markup instead.)

> that uses best practices (CF9 has changed so many things now:
>   scripted components, ORM)

Scripted components are *not* a best practise!

They are an *alternative* syntax (for people that prefer having non-descriptive braces everywhere) they do not offer anything you can't already do.

Comment: Peter: Thanks for helping me.  What I meant by css instead of tables is to not have the traditional table based layout that was so popular back in the 90s.

Here's an example of what I've done so far:
http://www.cfmzengarden.com/CFMZenGarden/001/index.cfm?&cssfile=001

You see that it uses the css zen garden template because I wanted to experiment with beautiful graphics and I'm not a graphics artist.  So I thought if I shoved my data into the css zen garden template I would have immediate access to hundreds of themes.

I wrote this back in CF8, so CF9 has really thrown me a curve.

Comment: The Orange Whip Studios examples in CF8 WACK use table based design.
One can argue that it's a database book, but what I'm trying to do is put it all together in one good CRUD application.
One that possibly has login security as well, since all CRUD applications need login security.

Comment: A table-based *design* is always wrong. Table is for *data*, not *design*/*layout*. My point is that dealing with databases increases the likelihood of dealing with data, and thus requiring tabular presentation of that data.

Comment: Oh, and another thing is to correctly handle error trapping.
All these requirements folded into one neat little CRUD application is what I'm looking for.